# Kinesis Data Analytics - Flink state serializer incompatible after recovering from Snapshot

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

We have our Flink application(version 1.13.2) deployed on AWS KDA. The strategy is that we do not want the application to stop at all, so we always recover the application from a snapshot when updating the jar with new changes.

Recently, we found a problem where a lower-level POJO class is corrupted. It contains a few getters and setters with wrong namings. This early mistake essentially hinders us from adding the POJO class with new fields. So we decided to rename the getter/setter directly. But it led us to the following exception after updating the application.

```
org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: The new state serializer (org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@46c65a77) must not be incompatible with the old state serializer (org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer@30c9146c).
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.updateRestoredStateMetaInfo(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:704) at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.tryRegisterKvStateInformation(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:624)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.createInternalState(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:837) at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyedStateFactory.createInternalState(KeyedStateFactory.java:47) at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlStateFactory.createStateAndWrapWithTtlIfEnabled(TtlStateFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AbstractKeyedStateBackend.getOrCreateKeyedState(AbstractKeyedStateBackend.java:301) at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.getOrCreateKeyedState(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:315) at
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.getOrCreateKeyedState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:494) at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.open(WindowOperator.java:243) at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:442)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:582) at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55) at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:562)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647) at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:537) at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:764) at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:571)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

As far as we understand, the failure happens specifically in the 2 CoGroup functions we implemented. They are both consuming the corrupted POJO class nested in another POJO class, **Session**. A code snippet of the Cogroup function is shown below. BTW, we are using google guava list here, not sure if it causes list serializer problem.

```java
public class OutputCoGroup extends CoGroupFunction<Session, Event, OutputSession> {

    @Override
    public void coGroup(Iterable<Session> sessions, Iterable<Event> events,
            Collector<OutputSession> collector) throws Exception {

        // we are using google guava list here, not sure if it causes list serializer problem
        if (Lists.newArrayList(sessions).size() > 0) {
            ...

            if (events.iterator().hasNext()) {

                List<Event> eventList = Lists.newArrayList(events);
                ...
```

As we can see in the input, the **session** is the POJO class that contains the problematic POJO class.

```java
public class Session{
   
    private problematicPOJO problematicpojo;
    ...
}
```

The problematic POJO class has 2 Boolean fields with the wrong getter/setter namings(literally missing **Is** :´<). Other fields in the class are ignored, they do not have any issues.

```java
public class problematicPojo {
    
    private Boolean isA;
    private Boolean isB;
    ...

    public getA(){ ... }
    public setA(...){ ... }
    public getB(){ ... }
    public setB(...){ ... }
    ...

}
```

We have looked up some possible solutions.

1. Using State Processor API -> AWS does not provide access to KDA snapshots, so we're not able to modify it
2. Providing TypeInformation to the problematic POJO class -> did not seem to be working

We are thinking of specifying listStateDescriptor in the cogroup function(changing to RichCoGroup) to be able to manually update the states when recovering from a snapshot. But we could not get too much insight from the official docs. Is anyone here familiar with this method and can help us out?

Thank you!